# Applying a specific symbology to multiple feature classes within a geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-class

I have a file-geodatabase with 100 point feature classes within it, each use the default single dot symbology. I was curious if it would be possible to change every feature class to a different symbology and to retain said symbology within the geodatabase.

So if I needed to remove the feature class from my project and then bring it back later it would keep the symbology I applied to it instead of the default point symbology.

I've tried applying a "Batch Apply Symbology From Layer" but if I was to remove the feature class from my project, and bring it back, it reverts back to the default symbology.

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2 if that is useful to know.

Comment: Data tables are just data tables, and there is no symbology property for a feature class. You need to use a layer file to retain the symbology.

Comment: Good to know thanks Vince

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't store symbology to database (you may use [Dictionary symbology](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/dictionary-renderer.htm) but it's probably not desirable in most case as it may need to change data structure).

As a workaround you may use :

- Style : create a style corresponding to your symbology then you may use [Match Layer Symbology To A Style](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/match-layer-symbology-to-a-style.htm) to quickly reaply you symbology to any similar layer
- LayerFile : save your layer with symbology as a [LayerFile (.lyrx)](https://pro.arcgis.com/fr/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layerfile.htm) then you can add this layer and have the symbology, or if you add another similar layer you may use [Import symbology from another layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/mapping/layer-properties/import-symbology-from-another-layer.htm) and chose the .lyrx as the source